# Why do people exercise call options at a loss?

Tags: call-options, option-exercise, covered-call, covered-call-writing

I sold some call options for $2.55 premium at strike price of $130.  At expiration, the market price was $130.55.  I thought the option was not deep in the money and at a loss of $2, hence I didn't buy to close.

On Monday, I found out the option was assigned and all my shares of stock were bought away at $130 per share.

Question is:

1. Why do people exercise call options at a loss?
2. Should I always buy to close at expiration?

Comment: To be clear, when you say "lost all of my stocks", you mean "received $130 per share for my stocks", right?

Comment: What do you mean by “the option was adjusted”? Do you mean “... exercised”?

Comment: @Lawrence I suspect OP means _assigned_.

Comment: For those that don't know the difference, the owner has the option to exercise a long option.  The seller is assigned.

Comment: Did you consider in your numbers that 'one' option typically is for 100 shares? So exercising them got someone 55$, not 55 cent.

Comment: Really bad idea to play with options if you don't understand what happened to you man

Comment: @CBauer au contraire - its a great way to learn :-) Just don't put too much money into it!

Answer (score 47):

The price at which you sold the option, or at which someone else bought it, has no bearing on exercise. Someone holding a long option to expiration will exercise it if it's *in the money*, which this one was.

The person exercising it was likely not the same person who bought it from you at $2.55, but even if it was, the fact that they had a loss is irrelevant. They gained $0.55 by exercising versus letting it expire unexercised. Or if you prefer, they had the choice between a loss of $2.55 and a loss of $2.00. Of course they exercised. The purchase price of the option was a sunk cost for them.

If you are holding a covered call close to expiration and do not want your stock to be assigned, then yes, you should buy to close. Even if the call is out of the money, it can be a good idea to buy for $0.01 or $0.05 just to eliminate risk.

Comment: "The price at which you sold the option, or at which someone else bought it" I think you should say "premium" rather than "price", to avoid confusion with the strike price (which seems to be the core of the OP's confusion).

Comment: A classic sunk cost fallacy.

Answer (score 30):

You do not understand the fundamentals of options.  This option assignment and loss of your stock is the result of that.  With all due respect, get a good options book and spend some time with it.

An in-the-money has intrinsic value.  At expiration it is the price of the stock less the strike price.  IOW,  your call was worth 55 cents.  Not exercising meant that the owner would have thrown $55 dollars away per contract.

You have made the assumption that the original buyer still holds the call that you sold.  While it's possible that your short calls were the only calls traded in the existence of this option, the probability of that is infinitesimal.  In reality, your calls could have been bought and sold many times over with some of the subsequent owners making money and others losing.

In the US, if any option is one cent or more in-the-money at expiration, the Option Clearing Corp (OCC) will automatically exercise it  whether it is long or short. This is called Exercise by Exception. For equity options, you will end up with a long or short position in the underlying (index options are cash settled).  If you are long the option, you can designate to the OCC via your broker that it is not auto exercised at expiration. This would make sense if it is ITM by pennies and your commission and/or fees to close the position exceeds the ITM amount.

Answer (score 14):

A major principle of decision-making is that one should compare an option to other options you currently have. Much angst and suboptimal behavior is caused by people instead making their decisions based on comparing an option they have to an option they don't have (just in case it's not clear, I mean "option" as in "a possible course of action", not "stock option").

Suppose there's a new phone coming out that you're interested in. The only places that will be selling it are Website A and Website B. Website A says that if you pay a $2.55 reservation fee now, you'll be able to buy it for an additional $130. Website B says that they haven't decided what price to sell it for yet; they'll let you know when it comes out. $132.55 sounds like a great deal to you, so you pay the reservation fee to Website A.

Now the phone comes out, and Website B says they're selling the phone for $130.55. Which website should you buy it from? Getting it from Website A means paying a $2.55 reservation plus a $130 purchase price, for a total expenditure of $132.55, which is more than what Website B is asking for. So it appears that Website B is a better option.

However, that's comparing "pay the reservation fee and then pay the purchase price for Website A" to "don't pay anything to Website A and buy it from Website B". But that's not an option that's available to you anymore. You've already paid the reservation fee. It's what's known as a "sunk cost": it's a loss that you've already incurred, and is not affected by any future choices.

The reservation fee is lost regardless of which website you buy it from. If you buy the phone from Website B, the total amount of money the phone will cost you is $133.10. So given your *current options*, Website A is the best choice.

When your buyer bought the call from you, they paid a $2.55 premium, or "reservation fee", for the right to buy the stock for $130. The total cost of buying the stock using the call is $132.55, which is higher that the cost of just buying the stock on the exchange. However, just buying the stock on the exchange is not an option for them. Their options are to lose the $2.55 and pay $130 to exercise the call, or to lose the $2.55 and pay $130.55 to buy from the exchange.

The $2.55 is lost either case. One doesn't get one's money back if one doesn't exercise the option. If one did, there would be no point in selling options.

Comment: "So it appears that Website A is a better option." you probably wanted to say "B is a better option" or "A is a worse option".

Comment: This is the most complex and convoluted answer that I have ever seen, attempting to explain intrinsic value. It's simply the  underlying price  minus strike price for calls and strike price minus underlying price for puts (for options that are in-the-money).

Comment: @BobBaerker If "underlying price minus strike price" were to explain it for OP, I don't think they would have asked their question in the first place.

Comment: @BobBaerker Actually, I think the explanation is quite clever. It avoids all the technical jargon and gets the point across quite clearly with a very relatable example.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus - If you're going to utilize options, you need to understand ultra basic concepts like Intrinsic value and you need to   be able to do simple math.  IOW, If A is greater than B then all you need to know is how to  subtract number B from number A.  If you need such a complex explanation to understand that  then  options are definitely not for you.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus - Here's all the technical jargon that you need to understand what intrinsic value is: (1)  Intrinsic Value of a Call = Spot Price – Strike Price and (2) Intrinsic Value of a Put = Strike Price – Spot Price (if either of these calculations yields a negative number, there is no intrinsic value).   That's what the OP missed.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you describe, buying the option was a mistake. However, exercising the option makes money: You buy 100 shares at $130 each and sell them immediately for $130.55, making $55 profit.

The fact that you spent $255 for the privilege of making $55 doesn’t mean you shouldn’t take the $55. It’s like paying $20 for lottery tickets and winning $10; you lost $10 but you take the prize because otherwise you lose $20.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense.  The OP sold a covered call so he received (not spent) $255.  Whether the owner of the option made money or not would depend on what he paid for the long $130 call.  Selling the option to close usually makes more sense unless one's intent is to own the shares. There is no $55 profit from selling the option.  That's merely capturing salvage value.